# Using the coefficients of regression for giving weight to the data

Tags: regression, clustering

I want to perform clustering on my data set. I used spectral clustering and obtained an acceptable result. In an effort to (maybe) improve the result, I thought of applying a linear regression on my data set and use the coefficients resulted from the regression as weights for my variables in the data set, since I am currently giving equal importance (no weights) to the variables used for clustering. My main questions are:

1) Is it statistically a justified practice to use regression coefficients as weights for the data?

2) After performing the regression, I got a couple of negative values, should I just use the absolute value ignoring the sign?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't really follow your question, can you say more? Is this just all to (possibly) improve the inputs to your clustering? If you already have a clustering that you find acceptable, I'm not sure I see the point.

Comment: @gung Yes, as I said, the result is acceptable but since I intuitively see that  for my particular task some variables have more importance than others, I decided on using regression to find the relative importance.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. "Relative importance" for what? A clustering has no response variable, whereas regression does. If you regress the cluster membership onto your variables, you'll only get back the importance that already went into the clustering.

Comment: @gung Sure, I have a response for my regression, which is the response I will be using to analyze the cluster members after the clustering.

Comment: So was the response no available to the clustering? Do you intend to ultimately regress the response onto the clustering you found?

Comment: @gung Yes, exactly.